# What are these coax connectors called?

Tags: connector, identification, coax

These are the connectors you can typically find on the back of stereo head units in cars, to connect the FM radio antenna.

I measured the external diameter at ~10mm.

You can easily find a ton of such products by googling "ISO antenna connector". But they all are various kind of adapters sold on alibaba or car accessories shops. I need to find some source for the mating PCB connector, but I don't know what is the "official name" of that type of connector.

There *has* to be an official name, though, since it seems to be an ISO standardized connector. The number of the ISO standard it adheres to would satisfy me enough.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: Looks more like an RCA connector

Comment: @Trevor RCA doesn't fit. The center pin of the RCA is way too big, although the external diameter seems similar.

Comment: This is an automotive equipment. They have their own, proprietary connectors.

Comment: It definitely looks like an ISO female antenna connector.  But I have no idea where to buy them.

Comment: check this out http://www.ebay.co.uk/bhp/iso-to-din?clk_rvr_id=1374132123756&rmvSB=true     and    https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Female-Fakra-to-Female-ISO-Aerial-Antenna-Adapter-Converter-Car-Radio-Stereo-040-/162766936115?clk_rvr_id=1374192300908&rmvSB=true

Comment: go to auto junkyard and get a scrap radio

Comment: It looks proprietary, but take a look at F connectors.